# "clear" is not available in batch processing in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, batch-processing, actions

I am trying to run an action which involves 3 “clear” steps and 1 “transform” step in Illustrator on `.pdf` files. I record the action and proceed to batch process, and I get an error that says:

> The object “clear” is currently not available.

I don't know how to correct this. This is Illustrator v 24.2.3

Comment: You can't use Cut.. or simply delete?

Comment: I did use delete, but the action marks it as clear

Comment: Sounds like your action has no selection

Comment: oh right! is there a way to select the same element in each of the multiple files in the action?